# Is object std::shared_ptr findable by its std::weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

So I have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> myListOfT;` and I have a `std::weak_ptr<T> ptrToOneT;` that was created from one of the pointers used to fill that container (say I have it inside a callback function). Will `std::find` on that container and my `weak_ptr` give me an iterator to the original `shared_ptr` (if such one exists in the collection)? Is it guaranteed somewhere in standard or is this implementation dependent?

Comment: The short answer is yes but you may need to cast the values returned by `get()`  to the absolute base pointer before doing the comparison.

Comment: Obtain a `shared_ptr` with `weak_ptr::lock()`, then pass that to `std::find`. You'll find some pointer referring to the same object.

Comment: Also, by locking, you prevent the object the weak_ptr point to from being deleted if the reference count goes to zero eg. in another thread.

Comment: What @IgorTandetnik said. When you have a `weak_ptr`, then you may or may not be able to get a `shared_ptr` from it with `.lock()`. There is no point searching to find the pointer. If you want the iterator, lock the `weak_ptr` and search for the resulting `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Answers in comments!

Answer (score 4):

We can get away *without* locking the `weak_ptr` by using `std::weak_ptr::owner_before`. I'll use a slightly more verbose solution than necessary and introduce `owner_equal`, which is the counterpart to `std::owner_less`:

```
template<typename T>
class owner_equal
{
private:
    template<typename L, typename R>
    static bool e(L const& l, R const& r)
    { return !(l.owner_before(r)) && !(r.owner_before(l)); }

public:
    using S = std::shared_ptr<T>;
    using W = std::weak_ptr<T>;

    bool operator()(S const& l, W const& r) const { return e(l, r); }
    bool operator()(W const& l, S const& r) const { return e(l, r); }
};
```

With this function object type, we can customize `std::find_if`:

```
using T = int;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> myListOfT =
  {std::make_shared<int>(0), std::make_shared<int>(1), std::make_shared<int>(2)};

int const pos = 1;
std::weak_ptr<T> ptrToOneT = myListOfT[pos];

auto pred = [&ptrToOneT](std::shared_ptr<T> const& e)
            { return owner_equal<T>{}(e, ptrToOneT); };

auto const r = std::find_if(begin(myListOfT), end(myListOfT), pred);
assert(r - begin(myListOfT) == pos);
```

The lambda can be replaced by a bind-expression such as:

```
auto pred = std::bind(owner_equal<T>{}, std::cref(ptrToOneT),
                      std::placeholders::_1);
```

---

[@davidhigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2412846/davidhigh) suggested an optimization:

```
template<typename FwdIt, typename T>
FwdIt findWeakPtr(FwdIt b, FwdIt e, std::weak_ptr<T> const& w)
{
    if(w.expired()) return e;
    else
    {
        auto pred = [&w](std::shared_ptr<T> const& e)
                    { return owner_equal<T>{}(e, w); };
        return std::find_if(b, e, pred);
    }
}
```

(not tested)

This also slightly changes the behaviour: If the `weak_ptr` is "empty", e.g. having been created from an empty `shared_ptr` or via the default ctor, it will compare equal to any empty `shared_ptr` via `owner_equal`. However, `weak_ptr::expired` is true in that case. Therefore, the optimized version will not find empty shared pointers in the range.

---

Should empty shared pointers be found in the range?

Consider:

```
using T = int;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> myListOfT =
  {std::shared_ptr<T>(), std::shared_ptr<T>()};

int const pos = 1;
std::weak_ptr<T> ptrToOneT = myListOfT[pos];

auto const r = my_weak_ptr_find(begin(myListOfT), end(myListOfT), ptrToOneT);
auto const r_pos = r - begin(myListOfT);
```

Empty shared pointers are *equal*. Therefore, if you allow finding empty shared pointers, `r_pos != pos && r != end(myListOfT)` is possible. For example, the first version of the algorithm in this answer yields `r_pos == 0`.

---

For additional context, see:

- [N1590 - Smart Pointer Comparison
  Operators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1590.html)
- [Equality-compare std::weak_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301916/equality-compare-stdweak-ptr)

Comment: +1, nice find, but I think you could bypass the whole search if the weak_ptr is expired? This one would get away with O(1) instead of O(N).

Comment: @davidhigh Interesting. It might be worth though to measure it at least for small ranges, since I guess `expired` requires an atomic read.

Comment: As far I understood your approach, my comment holds only if you want to drop the `nullptr == nullptr` hits from the search (?) -- which is at least what I would intuitively want ... others might not, and then this is clearly advantageous.

Comment: @davidhigh Hmmm true. For some reason, I thought there could be no empty `weak_ptr`s (only expired ones).

Answer (score 1):

[`std::weak_ptr::lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) is how you "promote" a `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`:

```
std::weak_ptr<T> ptrToOneT;
auto observe = ptrToOneT.lock();
if (observe) {
    // observe now shares ownership of the one T
}
else {
    // there is no managed object or it has already
    // been destroyed
}
```

If `lock()` succeeds, then you have a normal `std::shared_ptr<T>` that you can use to `find()` like you would any other object in a container. Though you may not need to `find()` it since you already have it (unless you want to `erase()` it or something).

Side-note, with `shared_ptr`, it's not really meaningful to refer to the "original `shared_ptr`"

Comment: Can't `std::owner_less` be used?

Comment: @dyp I'm not sure. I've never heard of that before.

Comment: @dyp Sounds like a way better answer than this one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few days ago in my own code. According to my SO-research, it is possible to do what you asked for. Lock the weak-pointer and if the shared-pointer is not-expired, then use `std::find`

```
struct A{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A> > sptr_vec;
    std::weak_ptr<A> wptr;

    if(auto sptr = wptr.lock())
    {
        auto it = std::find(std::begin(sptr_vec), std::end(sptr_vec), sptr);
        if (it != std::end(sptr_vec))
        {
            std::cout<<"found"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the C++ standard itself is not that relevant here -- the heart of the comparison of the shared-pointers is a comparison of the contained raw pointers, i.e. addresses in memory are compared.

Alternatively, if you have a vector of weak-pointers, you could use `std::find_if` with a predicate that locks on the fly:

```
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<A> > wptr_vec;
    std::shared_ptr<A> sptr;

    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(wptr_vec), std::end(wptr_vec)
                         , [&sptr](auto const& w){ auto s = w.lock();
                                                   if (s) {return s == sptr;}
                                                   return false; });
    if (it != std::end(wptr_vec))
    {
        std::cout<<"found"<<std::endl;
    }
```

Note that fot this application, I would consider the equivalence of `nullptr` with itself, i.e. that `nullptr == nullptr` is `true`, as unwanted. Thus I excluded this case from the predicate (and also from the search in the first code block).

**EDIT:** just considered the `owner_lock` solution by @dyp, which is advantageous if it is just about the search.